# Comment triggers and Jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins

How do I do the following?

I want a comment in a Git pull request to trigger a Jenkins build. From that comment I want to get a server number that I will use to run automated UI tests against.

So basically, someone comments:

```
run AT against server 10
```

That triggers a Jenkins build that runs automated UI tests against server 10.

How can I get that done using Jenkins and a plugin?

Comment: Is the comment the commit message, or in source code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a post-receive [server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks); the book even describes this situation:

> you can even parse the commit messages to see if any tickets need to
>   be opened, modified, or closed

You also need to use the Jenkins [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) API to kick off the build with the correct build parameters. The API is well-documented within Jenkins: click the "REST API" link in the bottom right hand corner of a Jenkins page to find out more.

Comment: I need to parse the comments from the PR not commit message

Answer (score 0):

Using 'command' inside the commit message is one way to get what you need, but using meta-data using 'tags' seems better to me.